# How can strsplit be applied to create a list without blank " " elements

Tags: r

**Question:** How can *strsplit* be applied to create a list without blank " " elements when there is whitespace at the start of the string?

**Code:**

```
     text <- c(" Please help me with this problem")

     dat <- data.frame(text)
     doc.list <- strsplit(as.character(dat[, 1]), "[[:space:]]+")
```

**output:**
[1] ""        "Please"  "help"    "me"      "with"    "this"    "problem"

**What I want:**
[1] "Please"  "help"    "me"      "with"    "this"    "problem"

Comment: `strsplit(text, "(?<=\\w)\\s+", perl = TRUE)[[1]]` still whitespace on the splits, you can just do it in two steps with `trimws` perhaps `strsplit(trimws(text), "\\s+")[[1]]`

Comment: you cn trim white space prior to the split: `strsplit(trimws(as.character(dat[, 1])), "[[:space:]]+")`

Comment: ``unlist(doc.list)[which(nchar(unlist(doc.list))>0)]`` or ``doc.list[[1]][which(nchar(doc.list[[1]])>0)]``

Comment: @Phann you might like `nzchar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trim white space prior to performing the split:

```
strsplit(trimws(as.character(dat[, 1])), "[[:space:]]+")
#[1] "Please"  "help"    "me"      "with"    "this"    "problem"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 strsplit(as.character(dat[, 1]), "(?<=\\w)(\\s+)",perl=T)[[1]]
#[1] " Please" "help"    "me"      "with"    "this"    "problem"
```

Comment: That has preserved the space at the start of the string in the first item in the split list: `" Please"`, which isn't what was wanted.

Comment: Correct; however, it removed the blank " "  caused by the " Please". I decided to use: strsplit(trimws(as.character(dat[, 1])), "[[:space:]]+") from @dww

Answer (score 0):

You could use `scan()` instead.  It will strip that white space automatically.

```
scan(text=as.character(dat$text), what="", quiet=TRUE)
# [1] "Please"  "help"    "me"      "with"    "this"    "problem"
```